# Data Binding to the contents of a list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to bind the properties of the items in a list to a data grid. I have the following code:

```
  <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Name="LeftSettingsDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Setting Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Settings.SettingName}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Setting Type" Binding="{Binding Path=Settings.SettingType}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

But this produces an empty grid view.

Data is an object that has a list of `Settings`, which are objects that have two public properties: `SettingName` and `SettingType`.

Basically, the hierarchy is like this:
 1. Data
   1. Settings
     1. SettingName
     2. SettingType

The data  context is set in the main window's constructor, with `LeftSettingsDataGrid.DataContext = Data;`.

Why is the binding not working then?

Comment: Path=Data replace it by Path=Data.Settings and Path=Settings.SettingName by Path=SettingName and Path=Settings.SettingType by Path=SettingType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this as a tree in your datacontext you have a list that you display as many items, your item source is Settings, your display member is item.SettingName etc

```
  <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Name="LeftSettingsDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Settings}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Setting Name" Binding="{Binding Path=SettingName}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Setting Type" Binding="{Binding Path=SettingType}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

your ItemsSource is Data.Settings not Data

Comment: this is not the only way

Comment: of course, there are many ways to achive everything, but this is the way with the less code change in current example